# How to use / implement a created Google Cloud API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would be very happy if you could help me.
My problem is after using AutoML Vision UI to train my machine

https://beta-dot-custom-vision.appspot.com/vision/project/select?error_code=MISSING_PERMISSIONS_VIEW_EXISTIENCE&project=hypnotic-surfer-211909

I would like to implement my custom model but do not know how to do that.

In detail, I would like to use the result of PREDICT tab, which is in AutoML Vision UI, as a function namely `function A`. After that, I have some code in C# which will call `function A` to use.

Following is what I tried:

In Google Cloud Platform Console, at (PROJECT_NAME)$ directory,

- add request.json file (the content of this file was generated by AutoML Vision UI after training model)
- run curl command

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1/models/ICN1270506624001569882:predict -d @request.json

And here is the message that I got
`your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the automl.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server application use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your appllication, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.`

status: `PERMISSION_DENIED`

Please kindly tell me what I should do.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Comment: Did you use a service account for the access-token? The error seems to indicate you are trying to call it as "you, the user" instead of as "an application".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I got it a little bit. I am very new in GCP, so would I ask u a little more?: I had got request.json file and curl command which was generated automatically after I tried using AutoML API UI. Next, I don`t  how to use service account (I have created one) as well as json file, curl command (where should I put them on? where should I run the code?in GCP console or in client C# code?). Then, if I call it from a C# code (on behalf of an application), would you please give me some example code. I am sorry because I ask so much, but you are high appreciated. Thank you